how make it autostart "startx -- -nocursor" in opensuse/openbox?
i want make it automatically to start with no-cursor: startx -- -nocursor this is worked but this is command..i want to autostart to user: kiosk..
(but i don't want to use "unclutter")
i'm not understand where i will can add script or file configure startx with no-cursor..
.xinitrc? or other file configure..
i use opensuse 15.6 with openbox
so i ask here, i  hope find your help hand code.. :-)
thank you

The sensible way here is to not use startx, but simply use one of the several graphical display managers that opensuse brings, and which it starts by default – you must have taken explicit steps to not use one of them.
Your use case seems to be starting a specific xsession (openbox) with specific settings, automatically – exactly what display managers have been written for⁰.
So, don't reinvent the wheel, let go of your script that calls startx -- -nocursor, and instead

install a display manager (e.g. lightdm) and enable it to start automatically on boot (systemctl enable lightdm)
write the necessary options for calling X with -nocursor to a new lightdm config file, e.g., /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/90-nocursor.conf:

[Seat:*]
xserver-command=X -nocursor


for cleanliness, keep the autologin information in a separate config file, e.g. /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/91-autologin.conf

[Seat:*]
autologin-user={User name that should be logged in automatically}
autologin-session=openbox
autologin-user-timeout=0

openbox must exist as a .desktop file in /usr/share/xsessions/; the user must be in the autologin  group.

To start things in kiosk mode, simply put them in the openbox autostart folder, or write systemd user service files, if one thing needs to depend on the other¹


⁰ historically, they've been doing more, but with your opensuse box, they don't have to care about a lot of the things related to managing users, getting systems ready to log them in etc – that's all taken care of by the system daemon anyways.
¹ like  "this service is the browser and can only be started as soon as the internet connection is up", "this service can only be started after the browser is up, but I don't want to wait a fixed amount of time, but really start as soon as the browser is ready", "this service needs to connect to a central server", "this program can only run after the service has connected to the central server" kind of things.

hi thank you for reply. ok for let go "startx". opensuse has not folder: lightdm.conf.d and file 90-nocursor.conf.. i will add new folder and file? "systemctl enable lightdm: Failed to enable unit: Unit file lightdm.service does not exist."

ah, sorry, yeah opensuse often forgos creation of such configuration directories. I just tried, indeed, if you sudo mkdir /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d and put ….conf files in there, they get used. So, please create that folder and create the files in there.

ok , i add folder and file, result: WORKS! but if is it possible: -nocursor only for user:kiosk? other user will be disable "-nocursor"?

hm, no, since this is an X server option, you'd need to start a separate X server for that.

thank you. i added new user used command "useradd" but will need add group name " autologin"?

this makes no sense, it's lightdm that launches processes as the user, not anything else.

update: i did added autologin in new group (groupadd -r autologin). but not work for autologin with lightdm but i find issue for (maybe) Opensuse use file configure for autologin: '/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager' script: [DISPLAYMANAGER_AUTOLOGIN="kiosk"] so i want to know.. why to use file sysconfig instead not use to lightdm (file configure)??

Marcus Müller please read link: https://jfcarter.net/~jimc/documents/suse-42.1/lightdm.conf  there is add code but i don't know what is correct put new  code.. please...
